Accessing Turbine Wind Speeds in FLORIS v3.5 After Wake Calculation
Description:
I'm working with FLORIS v3.5 for a wind farm simulation project and have run into an issue accessing turbine-specific wind speeds following wake calculation. My goal is to analyze the wind speeds at each turbine to understand the impact of wake losses and optimize turbine placement.
After initializing FLORIS and setting up my wind farm layout with 80 turbines (arranged in 10 rows and 8 columns), I proceed to calculate the wake. Post-wake calculation, I intended to retrieve and print the wind speeds experienced by each turbine to further analyze performance variations across the farm. However, I encountered an AttributeError when trying to use what I believed was the correct method to access this data (get_turbine_states()), as it appears it doesn't exist in this version of FLORIS.
What I Tried:
I attempted the following code after wake calculation to access and print turbine wind speeds:
turbine_states = fi.get_turbine_states() turbine_wind_speeds = [state.wind_speed for state in turbine_states] print('Turbine wind speeds: ', turbine_wind_speeds)
This resulted in an AttributeError, indicating that 'FlorisInterface' object has no attribute 'get_turbine_states'.
Expected Outcome:
I expected to retrieve a list of wind speeds for each turbine in the simulation, reflecting the impacts of wake and allowing for further analysis of performance across different turbine positions.
Question:
Could someone guide me on the correct method or approach to access the wind speeds at each turbine after wake calculation in FLORIS v3.5? Is there a specific attribute or a method call that I'm missing, or has there been a change in the API that I'm not aware of?

Please post in https://github.com/NREL/floris/discussions and the NREL team will help you out.
